# Что в Visual Studio отвечает за рекомендации в коде?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Если поставить ReSharper, то он будет подсвечивать если namespace отличается от того места, где физически лежит файл.

Так же всякие советы, которые заменяют одни конструкции на другие(более новые).

Это нужно анализаторы кода какие-то сверху ставить или плагины?

Comment: ReSharper уже является плагином к студии. Замена конструкций называется рефакторинг.

Comment: Анализаторы могут быть встроены (в студию встроены) - и они же [доступны и через nuget](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers). И сверх того разные [узкозаточенные](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers). И для конкретной библиотеки. И кто во что горазд (на гитхабе их много). И свои. Ну и решапер предлагает свой набор анализаторов. Отвечая на вопрос - если студия не подсвечивает сама встроенными анализаторами, то возможно придется что-то установить, чтобы обрабатывалось.

Comment: [NamespaceFixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=p2410.NamespaceFixer) - корректирует пространства имён

Comment: Самые популярные анализаторы: StyleCop, FxCop, Roslynator.